# Multiply two matrices inside a loop in Python to

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on the following code to recognize faces:

```
def clasificaImagen(numVS, numEntre, I):

    if numVS > 70: # No puede haber mas de 400 valores singulares
        numVS = 70;

    if numEntre > 76: # Queremos al menos 100 imagenes de prueba
        numEntre = 76;

    # Importamos las imagenes
    personajes = np.array([144,109,200,121,200,77]);
    persuma=np.array([0,144,253,453,574,774,851]);

    # Declaramos nuestras variables
    E = []; #np.mat(4096, numEntre, 6); %zeros(4096, numEntre, 6);
    U = []; #np.mat(4096, numEntre, 6); %zeros(6,1);
    Uk = []; #cell(4096, numVS, 6); %zeros(6, 1);
    aciertos = 0; 
    pruebas = sum(personajes)-(numEntre*6);  
    pguess = 0; # El digito que el programa asigna a cada imagen

    # Calculamos las matrices de entrenamiento para cada digito
    print 'Generando conjuntos de entrenamiento';

    for j in range(0,6):
        # E(j) tiene dimension 76 x numEntre
        E.append(I[:, persuma[j]+1:persuma[j]+numEntre]);
        # U(j) tiene dimension 76 x 76
        u, S, V = np.linalg.svd(E[j]);
        U.append(u);
        # Uk(j) tiene dimension 76 x numVS
        uk = U[j];
        uk = uk[:, 1:numVS];
        Uk.append(uk);

        type(Uk[1])
        print 'Clasificando imagenes';

    for i in range(0,6): 

        rMin = 9999999; 
        P = I[:, persuma[i]+1+numEntre:persuma[i+1]]; 

        for h in range(0,(personajes[i] - numEntre)-1):
            z = P[:, h]; 

            for j in range(0,6):
                ukMult = Uk[j]*Uk[j].T;
                ukMult = ukMult*z;
                ukMult = z - ukMult;
                res = np.linalg.norm(ukMult);
                if res < rMin:
                    pguess = j - 1;
                    rMin = res;

            if pguess == i-1:
                aciertos = aciertos + 1;

    print 'Calculando porcentaje de aciertos';
    return 100*aciertos/pruebas;
```

The problem is on this line:

```
ukMult = Uk[j]*Uk[j].T;
```

What is happening? The comments on the code are in Spanish, but I just want to see if someone can explain what's the problem with the multiplication of matrices. If necessary, I can put the comments in English.

I think the multiplication is well-defined because is just the product of a matrix and its transpose, so there shouldn't be any problems.

Using

```
  np.dot(Uk[j]*Uk[j].T)
```

also didn't work.

Comment: Your code's indentation is off, making it hard to follow. Please consider fixing it so other people will have an easier time helping you.

Comment: Done. The comments move everything and I didn't notice.

Comment: Isn't `np.dot()` used for matrix multiplication?  What you've written is element-wise multiplication.

Comment: `*` is elementwise multiplication, use `np.dot` for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yes. That also didn't work. Maybe the problem is in the definition of matrices?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but np.dot didn't work.

Comment: maybe `m = np.matrix(Uk) ; result = np.dot(m, m.T)`

Comment: as for me `Uk` is two-dimensional list - not matrix - so you can't use `.T` and multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the numpy.dot() function, it takes two parameters, not one as you have shown above.  Try something like this:

```
np.dot(Uk[j], Uk[j].T)
```

The docs are here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

The example they list there looks like this:

```
>>> a = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
>>> b = [[4, 1], [2, 2]]
>>> np.dot(a, b)
array([[4, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Also check out the numpy.matrix class: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html